# Exercise with pulmonary stenosis

Tags: exercise, jogging

I have mild *congenital pulmonary stenosis*, which Wikipedia defines as:

> outflow of blood from the right ventricle of the heart is obstructed
>   at the level of the pulmonic valve. This results in the reduction of
>   flow of blood to the lungs.

It doesn't affect me at all in my daily life. Recently I thought I should start regular exercises, so I try to jog from time to time. What I want to ask are:

- How to tell if I am just using that as an excuse or am I really at my limit? My jogging habits are always run a little, walk a little, run a little, walk a little. I guess I switch when I am slightly out of breath.

I understand these are more medical related, but none of the doctors I have visited can tell me anything in depth.

- Is there a particular type of exercises that are good for people like me?
- Would weight training be related to this at all?

Comment: Have you seen a sports medicine doctor?

Comment: oh there are that kind of doctors? thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I would recommend a cardiologist and a sports doctor in that order. Anytime that the heart has known pathology, getting the medical blessing before starting exercise is pretty much mandatory in my book.

Answer (score 1):

If your condition is mild, then no exercise limitations are required.  It is best however to be examined by your own doctor, so that all factors may be considered.  Generally patients who have a pressure gradient of less than 40mmHg are under no exercise restrictions.
http://emedicine.medscape.com/article/891729-treatment